# Passing volatile variable as constant argument in a function

Tags: c, arm, embedded

I'm developing and Embedded code for a Cortex-M0 MC where I declare a variable as `volatile char TOS_Mins_Char[3];`
to store some values during an ISR which would be periodically changed.
I want to convert these characters to an integer using the `atoi()` function,
but `atoi()` has its argument type as pointer to a constant string: `int atoi(const char *);` This give me error unless I avoid the `volatile` keyword in the variable declaration. (Faced similar situation in other std functions also)

1. Is there any solution for this other than writing a user defined
   function?
2. If I use `const char TOS_Mins_Char[3];`, will it be a problem?
3. Is it mandatory to use the `volatile` keyword, what is its use in
   contrast to an ARM MC ?

Comment: `volatile` is mandatory in your case: it tells to compiler to perform no optimization for access to this variable (you need it because you access to it in normal mode and interruption mode). I think, best way is to copy locally your volatile buffer to a standard one, and work with standard

Comment: @Garf365: Any proposals exactly *how* to perform the "copy" in a save manner?

Comment: It is not clear if you need `volatile` just because you use the variable in an interrupt handler does not mean it has to be `volatile`. Please provide a [mcve] with **all** relevant information (it need not be runnable, but should represent all uses of that variabale. You also should first learn what the qualifiers `volatile` and `const` mean for a variable and a function parameter declaration. Your questions indicate lack of knowledge - no offence.

Comment: I'm storing the characters form a main array to another array to do some mathematical calculation, to be precise , I'm adding a constant offset to the time I get form a device, so I need to extract the characters representing the Hours(which is stored in this variable) in-order to convert it to minutes. The minutes are separately extracted and converted and added to this and then the constant for an offset of 5 hours. (few more cal are there).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `volatile` keyword is necessary to tell the compiler to reload the characters from memory for each access.

If you know the array will not be modified during the conversion, you can use a cast to silence the warning:

```
int value = atoi((const char*)TOS_Mins_Char);
```

Note that the value returned by `atoi()` might be completely bogus if the interrupt routine modifies the array in the middle of the conversion.  You can prevent this by disabling the interrupts around accesses to the array. To minimize the duration of processing with disabled interrupts, you might want to copy the array to a local array this way:

```
char buf[sizeof TOS_Mins_Char];
CLI;   // whatever macro use to disable interrupts
memcpy(buf, TOS_Mins_Char, sizeof TOS_Mins_Char);
STI;   // enable interrupts
int value = atoi(buf);
```

The problem with this approach is the non reentrency of the interrupt disable/enable mechanism: if interrupts are already disabled when entering the code, they will be enabled upon leaving, which is probably not intended and a likely cause of bugs in the calling code.

Another quick and dirty trick can be used to lower the likelihood of an interrupt clash:

```
int value, last = atoi((const char*)TOS_Mins_Char);
while ((value = atoi((const char*)TOS_Mins_Char)) != last) {
    last = value;
}
```

If the buffer was modified by the ISR during the conversion, the next conversion would produce a different result. The is a remove possibility that the next conversion also be interrupted by the ISR, but in a non life critical system, you might want to ignore this possibility.

Comment: The problem is, where `atoi` is used. The cast can be very wrong.

Comment: The last idea is problematic as the null character may disappear (string became shorter in the middle of `atoi()`).  The `memcpy()` idea is good but suggest refinement `SAVE_ENABLE(); CLI(); memcpy(); RESTORE_ENABLE();` to handle re-entrantcy.

Comment: @chux: good solution! I was too lazy to look up the proper macros.  Thank you.

Comment: @chqrlie  The `SAVE_ENABLE(); CLI(); RESTORE_ENABLE();` are just placeholder names to express the conceptual functionality.  Uncertain what applies for ARM.  Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: An even dirtier (but theoretically more robust) trick involves `union {uint32_t, char[3]}` and the inherent atomicity of aligned 32-bit loads guaranteed by the architecture...